# The system cannot find the file specified ionic build issue

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework

Here when I build same application with Ubuntu machine is working well wheather building same code apk to windows PC giving above titled error.

here is the [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLjGF.png)

Comment: Is this project capacitor?

Comment: No it is ionic 3 proeject